# Hasura aggregation in related tables

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I was evaluating Hasura GraphQL engine + Postgres on Heroku and have run into a situation. I have 2 simple tables as shown below;
**Employees**
[image: Employees table]

**Payrolls**
[image: Payroll Table]

Employees table and Payrolls have a foreign key employees.ID -> payrolls.employee_id
Employees table has a foreign key with itself employees.manager_id -> employees.ID

I have gone ahead and "auto-tracked" all the relationships in Hasura.

What I want to calculate is the "sum of salaries" for all employees reporting. But, when I'm using the Hasura explorer to form the GQL query, I'm not able to find the "sum" aggregation under the "managed_employees_aggregate" subquery.

The expected output is

```
[
{
    "full_name": "anuj gupta",
    "total_reportee_salary": 4000
},
{
    "full_name": "sowmya",
    "total_reportee_salary": 2000
},
    ... "total_reportee_salary" for everyone else is 0
]
```

Any suggestions or references is really appreciated.

Comment: can you share your query, please?

Comment: I have a Hasura query like this till now. Don't know how to proceed further as I don't see a way to sum up the salaries of the "managed_employees".
query MyQuery {
  employees {
    full_name
    managed_employees_aggregate {
      aggregate
    }
  }
}

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with a simple query. Instead you can create a view for it.

Answer (score 1):

**Answering my own question**

As suggested by **@Ambassel** in the comments I ended up creating a view

```
create view reportee_total_vw AS
select
    employees.manager_id,
    SUM(payrolls.salary)
from
    employees,
    payrolls
where
    payrolls.employee_id = employees."ID"
group by
    employees.manager_id
```

Next I created a relationship named "reportee" that bound the "ID" from employees table with the "manager_id" from the view.

After that I could issue the underlying GQL query to get the result I wanted (although not in the exact format, but I can live with that :))

```
{
  employees {
    full_name
    reportee {
      total_reportee_salary:sum
    }
  }
}
```